# img src with a function as name of file

Tags: angularjs

I have images in a folder saved as the **users name**. I want to display a clickable image from the `(name of user).png`. Using `AngularJS`

This is wrong but this is what I mean, I know I cannot use src with a function in it:

```
{{currentUser.name}} //the function

<md-button ng-click="Popup()"><a><img src="{{currentUser.name}}.png " width="200" height="200"></a> </md-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentUser is a function ?
you're using it as an object. share your javascript.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. All it does it get the current user's name as text

Comment: Use  `ng-src` instead
why ? because
  `<img ng-src="{{currentUser.name}}.png "/>`
 currentUser.name is evaluated and replaced by its value after angular is loaded.

Comment: Thank it worked. I knew there was a way but I didn't know what

Comment: Happy to help. now please check an answer that you found helpful and mark this topic closed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-src` instead of `src`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the src by ng-src.
Checkout the manual about ng-src:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc